# Wikipedia Article -- Legendre Transform

Tags: matrices, calculus-of-variations, vector-analysis

I was reading the wiki article on Legendre Transform. I would be grateful if someone could explain the section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation#Examples
ie how they arrived at the Legendre transform of the quadratic form.
Thanks.

Comment: Would it help you if we replace "derivative" with "gradient" in the multivariate case?

Answer (score 4):

$$f^*(y) = \sup_{x} \left(y^Tx - \frac1{2} x^TAx\right)$$
The supremum can be found by taking the vector derivative with respect to $x$ and setting it equal to zero.
$$\frac{\partial \left(y^Tx \right)}{\partial x} = y$$ and
$$\frac{\partial \left(x^T A x \right)}{\partial x} = \left( A+ A^T \right)x = 2Ax$$ since $A$ is symmetric. Note that the supremum exists only if $A$ is positive definite. (second order condition) Setting the first derivative equal to zero gives us $$x = A^{-1}y$$ Plug this in to get $$f^*(y) = \left(y^TA^{-1}y - \frac1{2} \left(A^{-1}y\right)^TAA^{-1}y\right) = \frac12 y^TA^{-1}y$$

**EDIT:** You can look up matrix calculus [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) and [here](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much, Sivaram.